# How to get Visual Studio IDE messages to show up?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

I use VS2019 community at home, and it often reports "messages" (in the messages tab of the error list) such as IDE0063. These are helpful for automatically updating old code to use the latest C# features.

At work, I use VS2019 professional and I do not see these messages showing up at all, even when the code should trigger them. I do see errors and warnings. The messages tab exists, but is empty. Is there something I need to do to enable these messages in Visual Studio?

Comment: Please, share the code, which causes the warnings. Also, are you using the same versions of VS in both cases?

Comment: Ever found out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you can't find how to open the "Error List" window?

To open `Error List`, you can follow `View -> Error List`.

[image]

Then the Error List will be displayed below.

If the issue is the warning message can't be displayed in the "Error List", you can go to `Project -> Properties... -> Build` to check whether `Warning level` is `4`.

[image]

Comment: I've clarified my question. I do see the messages tab in the error list. However there are no messages there. Does warning level affect messages? Also is 4 not the default?